# Combining year and month columns to form index for time series data

Tags: python, time-series

I have a rainfall dataset of the following format.

YEAR JAN FEB MAR  APR  MAY  JUN  JUL  AUG  SEP  OCT NOV DEC
1901 2.7 0.4 4.7 10.0 13.0 16.9 19.2 18.3 15.7 10.6 4.9 3.5
1902 4.1 3.2 7.5 10.3 10.0 15.1 18.2 17.4 15.0 10.2 6.3 3.5
1903 3.8 5.9 7.6  7.1 12.9 14.9 17.6 17.3 15.5 12.1 6.9 2.7
1904 3.0 4.6 5.5 10.3 13.6 16.3 20.2 18.5 13.9 11.2 5.4 4.8
1905 1.7 4.0 7.4  9.3 11.9 16.5 20.0 17.6 14.7  8.4 5.5 3.8

I need it to be in the following format so as to perform time series forecasting of in python.

DATE        RAINFALL
1901-01-01  2.7

1901-02-01  0.4

1901-03-01  4.7

1901-04-01  10.0

The DATE column has to be of the datetime datatype and the RAINFALL column should hold the value of the rainfall of a particular month of a year.

Please help me with performing this transformation.

Comment: This is pretty simple to code; what aspect of it are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have your *DataFrame* already created, so the description
below omits this step (and imports).

Start from definig a function, which will be applied later, to create
`DATE` column from `YEAR` and `MONTH` columns:

```
def cnv(row):
    datStr = '01 ' + row.MONTH + ' ' + str(row.YEAR)
    return pd.to_datetime(datStr, format='%d %b %Y').date()
```

Then proceed as follows:

1. Create a second DataFrame, with `YEAR` and month name as MultiIndex:

   ```
   df2 = df.set_index('YEAR').stack().to_frame(name='RAINFALL')
   ```
2. Convert the MultiIndex to regular columns, renaming (unnamed in original
   MultiIndex) *level_1* to `MONTH`:

   ```
   df2 = df2.reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1': 'MONTH'})
   ```
3. Create `DATE` column, applying the above created function:

   ```
   df2['DATE'] = df2.apply(cnv, axis=1)
   ```
4. And finally, drop `YEAR` and `MONTH` columns and change the column order:

   ```
   df2 = df2.drop(['YEAR', 'MONTH'], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
   ```

Two first steps can be chained into a single instruction, but I deliberately
wrote them separately, to ease test printout of the intermediate results.